# CASL Authorisation in a React app "Can" conditions have no effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, casl

I am trying to implement CASL Authorisation in a react app, I think there is something I am not quite understanding about how to implement it.

The standard Can components seems to work with the basic CRUD actions, but I have not been able to get the conditions to have any effect. I think I am missing something.

My current theory is that I need to be using TypeScript instead of plain Javascript to make the whole thing work. I don't know any TypeScript at the moment and I really want to push forward with my App instead of having to learn another language. I will learn TypeScript if I have to though, I need to know if its worth doing. Below is a boiled down version of what I have built so far.

[Example on Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-kate-2hypo?file=/components/ThingManager.js:0-924)

**Expected Behaviour**
I would expect the app to show that the person can read and create Thing records. They should also be able to update or delete the specific Apple record.

*Expected Output:*
I can look at things
I can create a thing
I can update this apple
I can delete this apple

**Actual Behaviour**
It ignores anything to do with the conditions and allows create, read, update and delete on everything.

*Actual Output:*
I can look at things
I can create a thing
I can update any thing
I can delete any thing

**The main app**

```
import "./styles.css";
import ThingManager from "../components/ThingManager";
import AbilityContextComponent from "../components/AbilityContextComponent";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AbilityContextComponent>
        <ThingManager />
      </AbilityContextComponent>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Ability Context Component**
For building the ability context and wrapping up the generation of abilities

```
import React from "react";
import { AbilityContext } from "../src/Can";
import { defineAbility } from "@casl/ability";

class AbilityContextComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const ability = defineAbility((can) => {
      can("read", "thing");
      can("create", "thing");
      can("update", "thing", { userId: 3 });
      can("delete", "thing", { userId: 3 });
    });

    return (
      <AbilityContext.Provider value={ability}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AbilityContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default AbilityContextComponent;
```

**The Can component is generated here**

```
import { createContextualCan } from "@casl/react";
import React from "react";

export const AbilityContext = React.createContext();
export const Can = createContextualCan(AbilityContext.Consumer);
```

**Finally a component where authorisation on "Thing" might be used**

```
import React from "react";
import { Can } from "../src/Can";

class ThingManager extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const thing = {
      Name: "Apple",
      Description: "this is an Apple",
      Colour: "Green",
      UserId: 3
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Manage your things here</h3>
        <Can I="read" a="thing">
          <p>I can look at things</p>
        </Can>
        <Can I="create" a="thing">
          <p>I can create a thing</p>
        </Can>
        <Can I="update" a="thing">
          <p>I can update any thing</p>
        </Can>
        <Can I="delete" a="thing">
          <p>I can delete any thing</p>
        </Can>
        <Can I="update" this={thing}>
          <p>I can delete this {thing.Name}</p>
        </Can>
        <Can I="delete" this={thing}>
          <p>I can delete any {thing.Name}</p>
        </Can>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ThingManager;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking for was information on how to change the "Subject" which is CASL's term for the thing you are trying to set rights on. In this instance, what I am calling "thing".

It turns out there are many ways to detect the subject type.

[Subject Type Detection](https://casl.js.org/v5/en/guide/subject-type-detection)

Generally they all involve telling the Can component what the subject of the incoming object is.

The basic method is to call the function **subject** on the object you are passing to "this".

**Import subject from "@casl/ability"** and call it like **subject("thing", apple)**

[Working version on CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-hooks-cilko)

```
import React from "react";
import { Can } from "../src/Can";
import { subject } from "@casl/ability";

class ThingManager extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const apple = {
      Name: "Apple",
      Description: "this is an Apple",
      Colour: "Green",
      UserId: 3
    };
    
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Manage your things here</h3>
        <Can I="read" a="thing">
          <p>I can look at things</p>
        </Can>
        <Can I="create" a="thing">
          <p>I can create a thing</p>
        </Can>
        <Can I="update" a="thing">
          <p>I can update a thing</p>
        </Can>
        <Can I="delete" a="thing">
          <p>I can delete a thing</p>
        </Can>
        <Can I="update" this={subject("thing", apple)}>
          <p>I can delete this {apple.Name}</p>
        </Can>
        <Can I="delete" this={subject("thing", apple)}>
          <p>I can delete any {apple.Name}</p>
        </Can>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ThingManager;
```

I had also gotten the theory of how Can works a bit wrong. You will notice in the working example that the "I can update a thing" and the "I can delete a thing" texts are still showing. This is because the general "Can I update a" and "Can I delete a" type components all show their children as long as the user can update/delete at least one thing. Its not saying "this user has access to everything".